# Magic square generation

Tags: matrices

I have a few question regarding [magic squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square).
According to wikipedia a magic square is defined as an `n x n` matrix where the rows in each direction (horizontal, vertical, diagonal) sum up to the same number, the magic constant.

When generating such a magic square what conditions need to be met?

1. Can I generate a magic sqaure for any number in a 4x4 square where the magic constant d is > 4? If not, how to I figure out what's the smallest number I can generate a magic square for a sqaure of a certain size?
2. How many combinations do exist for a magic constant d in an `n x n` square?
3. What's the most efficent algorithm to find all magic squares for for a given magic constant and a given square width?
4. Are their certain numbers for which you can not generate a magic square (except those where `d < n`)

I hope someone can clarify this for me a bit.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: you missed at least one part of the definition of a magic square.

Comment: Do you want only standard magic squares or also arbitary magic squares ?

Comment: @Peter magic squares which only result in d in the horizontal, vertical and diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Question 1

From the source, [Magic Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square), it says that 'A magic square is a n*n square grid (where n is the number of cells on each side) filled with **distinct positive integers**, which means that the numbers in the cells cannot have decimals, which means that you can't have the magic number as four for 4x4 square. Though you can probably create a magic square with decimals if you want.

For Question 2 and 3

Here is a useful document:

[Magic Squares](https://minerva.leeds.ac.uk/bbcswebdav/orgs/SCH_Computing/FYProj/reports/0304/Tang.pdf)

For Question 4

No. Source: [Magic Squares](http://www.mrexcel.com/tip069.shtml)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please update the links above? They do not work.